# Excel - 3D interpolation

Tags: excel, 3d, interpolation

I have to make a 3D graph in Excel. On the x-axis I want to make a linear distribution, but that doesn't work.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: Graph]

But , for example, the distance between 40-60 should be twice as large.

Can you help how I should do this? I can't get interpolation to work in 3D graphs :(
The .XLSX can be found [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3523511/OMNeT.xlsx).

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to edit the x-axis properties and change the text labels to numbers?

Comment: Yes, but that did not work. For now I have just interpolated the missing values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who is interested: I ended up manually interpolating the 'missing values'!